# Angular2 and how to add a dynamic property based on condition

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular2.

I'm trying to add a property to a `<select>` ONLY if the class property `type` is 'withName'

If that is the case, the rendered select should be:

```
<select class="select-input"
  (change)="handleChange($event)">
```

If not, the same but with the `name` property

```
<select class="select-input" name="some-name" 
  (change)="handleChange($event)">
```

How can I conditionally check this to render one or the other in the view or template?
I tried *ngIf and ng-template for else but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just conditionally bind the `name` attribute:

```html
<select class="select-input" [attr.name]="withName ? 'some-name' : 'another-name'" 
  (change)="handleChange($event)">
```

However, if you don't want the `name` property at all, you're going to need to have two separate implementations and use `*ngIf`

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxogcw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding